# node_load_multiple() can it go through the array?

Tags: arrays, drupal

I'm trying to do this to get the "floor" value of my node :

```
$type = "desk";
$floor = '2';
$nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('field_floor["und"][0]["value"]' => $floor, 'type' => $type));
```

I can get all my desk if I'm just doing `$nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => $type));` and I can find a deck with for exemple the title, but is it possible to go through the arrays to get the 'value' and check it in the query ?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

To get value of a field you have multiple methods :

Field get item:

```
$nid = 2;
$node = node_load($nid);
$floor = field_get_items($node , 'node', 'field_floor');
$floor = reset($floor); // or loop on it, here take first value if multiple
echo $floor['value'];
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_get_items/7.x

Entity metadata wrapper:

```
$nid = 2;
$node = node_load($nid);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$floor = $wrapper->field_floor->value();
echo $floor;
```

https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/entity-api/entity-metadata-wrappers

Direct way :

```
global $language; // take current language 
$nid = 2;
$node = node_load($nid);
echo $node->field_floor[$language->language][0]['value'];
```